# Driver for .Net Application using NHibernate to support failover functionality of AWS Aurora

Tags: .net, nhibernate, driver, failover, amazon-aurora

I am migrating my Database from MSSQL to Aurora(MYSQL). The application is using .net and NHibernate. We tried the Nhibernate driver for MYSQL "MySql.Data" and it works fine for all use cases but failover. When a failover happens, the connection is not reset and it keeps trying to connect to the old IP from the writer cluster and so all the write call fails with the exception "The MySQL server is running with the --read-- only option so it cannot execute this statement". This only gets resolved after doing an IISRESET on the web servers.

I know that for java, the MariaDB connector is able to take care of this use case. Is there any similar driver available for .net applications?
What is the best practice to handle such use case?

Answer (score 2):

MariaDB java connector has a specific implementation for Aurora. There is none that i know for .net. 
Still the normal solution is using cluster DNS : Aurora provide different DNS link:

- one for each instance
- cluster endpoint (like xxx.cluster-yyy.zzz.rds.amazonaws.com)
- reader endpoint (load balanced) (like xxx.cluster-ro-yyy.zzz.rds.amazonaws.com)

Using the cluster endpoint, you are using the current writer instance. When there is a failover, this DNS will point to the new master, but this change take some time (<60s), so during that interval you may end up pointing to the previous master, that if available will be now a slave pointing to a new paster.

The best solution is to query "show global variables like 'innodb_read_only'" checking that result is OFF to validate connection.

Comment: The drivers we have used so far are not helping and the application keep connecting to the old writer even though nslookup on the web servers return the IP of the new new writer. We reduced the default DNS caching from 2 minutes to 2 seconds and tested it. The application only recovers if we do an IIS reset or an app pool recycle.

Comment: "The best solution is to query "show global variables like 'innodb_read_only'" checking that result is OFF to validate connection." - Is there any feature in the .net driver to keep checking the variable or we need to build polling service?

Comment: Mariadb ODBC driver seems to be working fine with Aurora Failover but it is not working with Foreign Key Relationships in NHibernate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594552/odbcexception-error-23000-ma-3-0-35-7-12cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row

Comment: @Tulika were you ever able to find a Aurora failover solution?