# Is there a way to clear the connection pool in NHibernate?

Tags: mysql, .net, nhibernate, dbconnection

Application is using `.NET` and `NHibernate` to connect `MySql`. 
As per my unerstanding `NHibernate` internally using the `DbConnection`. Is there anyway to clear the connection pool when using `DbConnection`.

We know that `ClearPool()` static method available for  `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` and `ReleaseObjectPool()` available for 
`OleDbConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the underlying database connection from a session instance. You could attempt to cast this to a type you know supports the ability to clear the connection pool.

Comment: I am not seeing ClearPool()  method even after cast with SqlConnection.

Comment: Is that because it's a `static` method? If that's the case then you shouldn't need to access a specific instance of a connection, which makes sense considering you're trying to affect the pool. However, with this approach, you need to be sure what concrete implementation NH is using.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50341191/driver-for-net-application-using-nhibernate-to-support-failover-functionality-o?noredirect=1&lq=1 This is the original problem. So we are trying to reset the connection pool during the failover

Comment: If the underlying connection is `MySqlConnection`, then there's a `ClearPool()` method you can use: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection_ClearPool.htm

Comment: Considering your original problem, have you thought about replicating something like Entity Framework's 'resilient connections'? Maybe with something like Polly.

Comment: 'ClearPool()' is not showing when use 'nHibernate-DbConnection'. Problem in 'resilient connections', the application keep connecting to the old writer